# Prove there is a unique continuous function satisfying this integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

This is a question from an old real analysis qual:

Prove that there is a unique continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) = \cos x + \int_0^x f(y)e^{-y}dy$$
for $x \in [0,1]$

I haven't seen any problems like this before and I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define a bounded operator on $C[0,1]$ (the Banach space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) by $Tf(x) = \cos(x) + \int_0^x f(y)e^{-y}dy$.

Observe that $\| Tf - Tg\|_\infty \leq \|f-g\|_\infty \int_0^1e^{-y}dy = (1-\frac{1}{e})\|f-g\|_\infty$, so that $T$ is a contraction.   By the [Contraction Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), there is a unique fixed point of $T$.

Comment: nice use of the contraction mapping theorem (+1)

Answer (score 2):

We derivate and we find the differential equation
$$f'(x)=-\sin x+ f(x)e^{-x}\quad \text{with}\quad f(0)=1$$
which has a unique solution by [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: Picard-Lindelof only gives local uniqueness.  There's a bit more to do here.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian There's a unique *maximal* solution.

Comment: Right, but you need to show that the maximal interval of uniqueness includes the entire interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating and rearranging, we get
$$
f(x)e^{-x}-f'(x)=\sin(x)
$$
With an integrating factor of $g(x)=e^{e^{-x}}$, where $g'(x)=-g(x)e^{-x}$ we get
$$
(f(x)g(x))'=-\sin(x)g(x)
$$
Then, we simply integrate and divide by $g(x)$ to get
$$
f(x)=\frac{e}{g(x)}-\frac1{g(x)}\int_0^x\sin(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
The constant of integration was chosen so that $f(0)=1$.